# Error: --alias must be specified using PEPK tool

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-app-signing

So I'm trying to Enroll a new App Sign In to publish a new application and I got the following error when I enter the following command

> java -jar "/path/to/pepk.jar" --keystore="/path/to/key_prod.keystore" --alias="myAlias" --encryptionkey="1230928312431093randomkey1231238u981y8u23" --output="/path/to/private_key.pem"

Error:

> Error: --alias must be specified 
>   USAGE: 
>   java -jar pepk.jar --keystore < release_keystore > --alias < key_alias > --encryptionkey=< encryption_key_hex > --output=< output_file >

Is my syntax ok? I don't understand why it says my alias is not specified.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Java version 1.8 the correct syntax was

> java -jar pepk.jar --alias=myAlias --keystore=myKey.keystore --output=private_key.pem --encryptionkey=c647randomKeyfde6a

I added the pepk.jar file and my keystore in the root of my folder when executing the command.

Comment: when trying to run
java -jar "C:\Users\Downloads\pepk.jar" --alias=name --keystore="C:\U sers\sai\Desktop\test.jks" --output=encrypted_private_key_path --encryptionkey=XXXYYYZZZ and using java 1.8 but getting 
Error: --encryptionkey must be specified

Comment: @AshishJain , I had the same issue and I changed the order again and it worked properly: java -jar pepk.jar --alias=myAlias --encryptionkey=c647randomKeyfde6a --keystore=myKey.keystore --output=private_key.pem